# SQL Wildcard Characters - What Am I Missing?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, case, wildcard

Trying to group the browser platforms by generic type instead of each individual version.

```
An error occurred while calling o73.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'BrowserPlatform' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 10)
```

This is the error I usually get when syntax is off slightly so I know I'm missing something here. Can you point it out?

```
spark.sql(""" SELECT
CASE WHEN BrowserPlatform IN 'iOS%' THEN 'iOS'
        WHEN BrowserPlatform IN '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
        WHEN BrowserPlatform IN '%iPad%' THEN 'iPad'
        WHEN BrowserPlatform IN '%iPhone%' THEN 'iPhone'
        ELSE BrowserPlatform
        END AS GenericBrowserPlatform
    FROM DATA
""").createOrReplaceTempView('Test')
```

| BrowserPlatform | GenericBrowserPlatform |
| --- | --- |
| iPhone, iOS 14 | iPhone |
| iOS 14 | iOS |
| Android 10 | Android |
| Android 11 | Android |
| iPhone, iOS 13 | iPhone |

Comment: You probably want to use the `LIKE` operator rather than `IN` (which expects parenthesis afterwards)

Comment: IN does not really make sense with wildcards -- wild cards are use with LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here in case it helps someone else.

LIKE instead of IN solves the problem